# Capture specific final URL in chrome extension and callback API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a chrome extension that capture specific URLs

`/profile/office365_emails_email/abc123456789`
 Etc..

(As long as it has `/profile/office365_emails_email/` in it)

The extension will take the value of `id`, in this example: `abc123456789`,
and will call a web API with this `id`.

The web API may not always be available, so the extension needs to handle this gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide information on whether you only want to run the extension for a specific URL or for all URLs, so I'm just going to assume the last.

In your background-script you can set up a listener for URL changes and react only to specific paths.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    const url = changeInfo.url
    if (url && url.indexOf('/profile/office365_emails_email/') !== -1) {
        // If this is part of the sub-url you wish for you can then extract the ID
        const URLelements = url.split("/")
        const id = url[url.length - 1]

        // Use the ID to call your API
    }
})
```